# generate probabilities from histogram

Tags: matlab, histogram, probability

suppose that we have following code

```
>> B=xlsread('data_generations1','A1','g8:g301');
>> [pxx,f]=periodogram(B,[],[],100);
>> [peaks,location]=findpeaks(pxx);
>> length(peaks)

ans =

    88

>> hist(peaks,40)
>> [pxx,f]=periodogram(B,[],[],100);
>> pxn=pxx./sum(pxx);
>> [peaks,location]=findpeaks(pxn);
>> hist(peaks,40)
>>
```

and we have following pictures

[image]

i want to generate  probabilities from this histogram in matlab so that sum of all these probabilities should be equal to 1,but i dont know well how to do,so please help me  ,thanks in advance

EDITED:
after  following instruction,i have got following picture

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't know the underlaying distribution, maybe the function ksdensity (Statistics Toolbox required) is useful:

```
x = [randn(3000,1); 15+randn(3000,1)];
figure; hist(x,40)
```

[image]

```
[f,xi] = ksdensity(x);
figure; plot(xi,f);
```

[image]

Comment: i will plot result,and pleas etell me what type of distribution it is ok?

Comment: what type of distribution it is?i have uploaded picture

Comment: I don't know the type of distribution of your data, but ksdensity don't require that information. If you know the distribution, probabily the function [histfit](http://www.mathworks.es/es/help/stats/histfit.html#inputarg_dist) is a better option.

Comment: i have asked  another question related to distribution,thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

You have to normalize so that the total probabilities sum to one.

Typically that means summing over the histogram or integrating if the function is continuous, then dividing.

Comment: peaks./sum(peaks) like this?

Comment: @datodatuashvili - Yes

Comment: but how to determine type of distributions?